# How do I make a subclass for defined cases?

Tags: c++

So, basically I have a class Vehicle and a subclass Car. If an instance of Car happens to be a "Black" car in the "Color" member, I should make what my teacher calls an "Automatic Subclass" which will add more members to this specific object showing that characteristic, for example, a red flag to the object Car. How do I make that class? Is it possible to add members after creating the object?

```
class Vehicle {
public:
    std::string model_name;
    std::string color;
    int HorsePower;
};

class Car : public Vehicle {
public:
    int wheel_size;
    int weight;
};
```

Comment: “Automatic Subclass” isn’t an established term in the context of OOP or C++. You will need to ask your teacher what they mean. As it stands, without additional context the assignment doesn’t make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The following part of your question makes no sense: "an instance happens to be ...":
Instances are not happening to be: they get constructed, accessed, modified and/or destroyed.

So your question becomes: "When an instance is constructed as being black, then something should be done", or "When an instance is modified to be black, then something should be done".

This has following consequences:

"When an instance is constructed as being black, then something should be done": this means that, when the constructor is launched, some other function or method should be called.

"When an instance is modified to be black, then something should be done":
Wow: how will you even know that anybody is modifying an attribute of your object? Well, the easiest way is to declare it as private, and it can only be modified using a public method, and when that method is launched in such a way that your attribute gets a certain value, in that particular case some other function or method should be called.

...

So, as mentioned by @Konrad already: the question is not clear enough. Please clarify the question.